# Angular ng-repeat not working due to scope loss

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to implement pagination on my webpage.

When I select a page on the pagination tab the following is executed:

```
$("#pagination-demo").twbsPagination({
  totalPages: 100,
  visiblePages: 7,
  onPageClick: function(event, page) {
    $scope.PaginateVideos(page);
  }
});
```

Which calls this function:

```
$scope.PaginateVideos = function(pageNum, searchcriteria) {
  var searchCriteria;
  searchCriteria = searchcriteria;
  return $http({
    url: '/videos/GetVideos?page=' + pageNum + '&search=' + searchCriteria,
    method: 'Get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).success(function(response, status) {
    if (status === 200) {
      $scope.VideoDetailsModel = {};
      $scope.VideoDetailsModel.Data = [];
      return $scope.VideoDetailsModel.Data = response;
    }
  });
};
```

When I check the source in my browse browser I can see that $scope.VideoDetailsModel.Data is updated with fresh data.

However the ng-repeat items shows old data.

After troubleshooting I can confirm that calling the onPageClick: event in the $("#pagination-demo").twbsPagination Is the source of the problem..

If I call the PaginateVideos function directly without paginating , ng-repeat works.

I have tried $scope.apply() .. example

```
$scope.VideoDetailsModel.Data = response
$scope.apply()
```

I can confirm that on pagination VideoDetailsModel.Data definitely has new data.

Can you please help…..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same ng-controller in two different section on my webpage

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be due to the change of reference object.

In your success handler you did this:

```
if (status === 200) {
  $scope.VideoDetailsModel = {};
  $scope.VideoDetailsModel.Data = [];
  return $scope.VideoDetailsModel.Data = response;
}
```

Can you try moving `$scope.VideoDetailsModel = {};` out to your controller scope? Something like:

```
$scope.VideoDetailsModel = {};

$scope.PaginateVideos = function(pageNum, searchcriteria) {
  ...
  return $http(...).success(function(response, status) {
    if (status === 200) {
      return $scope.VideoDetailsModel.Data = response;
    }
  });
};
```